# All Simulators (except one) went away from Xcode

Tags: xcode, ios7, ios8, ios-simulator

I startet my Mac and Xcode this morning and the first problem of the day is: All my simulators except iPad Retina (iOS 8) are away from the list. (take a look on the screenshots) So I've taken a look at the "Downloads" section in the preferences of Xcode and iOS 7.1 simulators are installed, too. So there should be iOS 7.1 and 8.1 simulators mentioned in the list. (iPad, iPad Retina, iPad Air and resizable iPad)

Here are some screenshots about my situation:
[image: Only one simulator mentioned there]

[image: iOS 7.1 simulators are installed]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CoreSimulator stores the simulator devices in ~/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices.

I suspect that you may have deleted ~/Library/Developer while your iPad Retina was running, so it was "recreated" when its state later changed.

You should not delete ~/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator.  If you want to delete devices, use the devices window.  To fixup this problem, quit everything using the simulator (Xcode, iPhone Simulator, Instruments, etc) and run the following in Terminal:

```
rm -rf ~/Library/*/CoreSimulator
killall -9 com.apple.CoreSimulator.CoreSimulatorService
```

Comment: Hi if you take a look on my comment you'll see, that i've already solved this. But thanks for this further explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Solution:
I've just got the solution to my own question.

1. Go to window -> devices
2. Hit "+" (bottom-left) and create the simulator-definitions you need
3. enjoy your workday :-)

Have a nice day!